# Is random vector a vector of observations or list of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

I am stuck on a very basic concept in probabilities. The question goes like this. Is a vector of observations of a random variable (for example a series of coin toss states) the same as a random vector? ( which I am thinking is a collection of observations of multiple random variables)

Comment: You won't like this answer, but I have seen both uses.  I'd say the more common one was "n-tuple of random observations".  But people do employ the other usage as well.  Context is critical.

Answer (score 1):

You can build vectors in different ways with different relationships between the vector's coordinates.

One example is to take a couple random quantities, like the number of Coke cans consumed from a particular soda machine, and the number of Pepsi cans from the same machine, and form a vector $\vec{x} = [c, p]$ and analyze it somehow.

Another way is to consider a time series of each, which could be thought of as vectors. Let $c_1, c_2, \ldots$ be number of Coke cans consumed on days $1, 2, \ldots$ of the experiment, then $\vec{y} = [c_1, c_2, \ldots]$ is a time series vector.

Both $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ are random but the relationship between the components is different.

I have to add that in the majority of texts, simple references to random vectors mean the first kind, not the second.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of any countable collection of random variables as a random vector, but it's often not useful to do.  Generally when we talk about random vectors it's because their individual elements are *dependent* and their joint relationship is of special interest.  This basically rules out the "random sample" case, for instance.